# not accepting null value in mysql

Tags: mysql

```
`CREATE TABLE DEPT 
( 
    DEPT_NO INT PRIMARY KEY, 
    D_NAME VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, 
    LOC VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL

);

CREATE TABLE EMP 
( 
    EMP_NO INT primary key, 
    E_NAME VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, 
    JOB VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, 
    MGR INT, 
    HIRE_DATE DATE NOT NULL, 
    SAL INT NOT NULL, 
    COMM INT, 
    DEPT_NO INT NOT NULL,
foreign key(dept_no) references dept(dept_no) 
);

INSERT INTO DEPT (DEPT_NO,D_NAME,LOC) 
VALUES ('10','ACCOUNTING','NEW YORK');

INSERT INTO DEPT (DEPT_NO,D_NAME,LOC) 
VALUES ('20','RESEARCH','DALLAS');

INSERT INTO DEPT (DEPT_NO,D_NAME,LOC) 
VALUES ('30','SALES','CHICAGO');

INSERT INTO DEPT (DEPT_NO,D_NAME,LOC) 
VALUES ('40','OPERATIONS','BOSTON');

insert into emp values(7369,"SMITH","CLERK",7902,"1980-12-17",800," ",20);'
```

`

Comment: ERROR 1366 (HY000): Incorrect integer value: ' ' for column 'COMM' at row 1  the error I am getting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You declared in the '**emp**' table the column '**comm**' as INT and in the insert you are inserting a string, the right thing would be:

```
insert into emp values(7369,"SMITH","CLERK",7902,"1980-12-17",800,0,20);
```

or

```
insert into emp values(7369,"SMITH","CLERK",7902,"1980-12-17",800,null,20);'
```

Answer (score 0):

here is your error `insert into emp values(7369,"SMITH","CLERK",7902,"1980-12-17",800," ",20)'`
just before the value `20` from last
its `" "` which just means that there's nothing and is a String `datatype` with space.
So to solve it make it as

use `default` keyword to `insert` `default` value in the table.
where here default value is `NULL`

```
insert into emp values(7369,"SMITH","CLERK",7902,"1980-12-17",800,default,20)'
```

**OR**

```
insert into emp values(7369,"SMITH","CLERK",7902,"1980-12-17",800,0,20)'
```

**OR**

Just use `NULL` keyword to insert null value in the `table`

```
insert into emp values(7369,"SMITH","CLERK",7902,"1980-12-17",800,NULL,20)'
```